# Issues updating subdocuments in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, heroku, subdocument, mlab

Excuse if this is a silly question, but I'm quite new to mongo.

I have documents with subdocument listed under `films`. I'm updating a single subdocument without issue on my localhost using;

```
db.update(
  { _id: req.params.id, 'films.filmId': req.params.filmId },
  { $set: {
    'films.$.watched': watched,
    'films.$.watchedAt': watchedAt
  }})
```

However, when testing it on Heroku with mLab it only ever updates the first subdocument listed in `films`, regardless of the filmId passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

This update is only updating the first array element because its using the $ operator.

The $ operator is a placeholder for the first element in the array that matches the query document. Documentation on this operator in the context of an update can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_).